# Destroy a specific md-menu

Tags: angularjs, material-design

A user can have a md-menu open and that menu can be closed when a certain situation happens in a subscribe method in the controller:

```
if (this.checkStatus(status)) {
    this.$mdMenu.destroy();
}
```

This if statement can also be true when a different md-menu (one that I don't want to close) is open. But this `this.$mdMenu.destroy();` destroys all md-menus on my application.

Comment: Which version of material.js do you use?

Comment: "angular-material": "~1.1.5",

Comment: how u open 2 menus? menu from menu?

Comment: Did you try hide() or close() or destroy($event)

Comment: @PetrAveryanov updated the question. The question is that I have a function that gets called in a certain situation and that method destroys all md-menus while it should target a specifc md-menu to destroy.

Comment: Are you using $mdMenu service? In most situations you should pass $mdMenu from view. But actually I do not understand problem - another menu, another html, pass whatever param to controller functions easily.